# Django: Give custom filtering methods to `QuerySet` objects of a specific model

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm defining a model in Django. I want to define a few custom methods for its `QuerySet` objects. (i.e. I want to define custom ways to filter instances of that object, in a way peculiar only to that model.)

Now, I could define those on the `Manager`, but then these methods will be accessible only on the `Manager` and not on any single `QuerySet` which is the result of any kind of filtering on that model.

So: How do I give the `QuerySet` objects of my model custom filtering methods?

Comment: are you looking for custom managers ? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need filter chaining extend `Queryset`.

One example from my current project:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class MemberQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def in_group(self, group):
        return self.filter(group_set__pk=group.pk)

    def not_in_group(self, group):
        return self.exclude(groups_set__pk=group.pk)

class MemberManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MemberQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def in_group(self, group):
        return self.get_queryset().in_group(group)

    def not_in_group(self, group):
        return self.get_queryset().not_in_group(group)

class Member(models.Model):

    # ...

    objects = MemberManager()
```

With this you can do:

```
Member.objects.in_group(one_group).not_in_group(another_group)
```

If you don't need filter chaining a manager with custom methods would be enough.
That's quite well covered in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

[This snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/) seems nice for faster `QuerySet` plug-in, but it is old (4 years) and **I've never tried it**.

Answer (score 4):

Resurrecting this to offer a better, cleaner way to do this.

From at least django 1.8 (not tested on anything earlier..it may or may not work, not sure when this API was introduced), there's a much nicer way to do this...

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class MemberQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def in_group(self, group):
        return self.filter(group_set__pk=group.pk)

    def not_in_group(self, group):
        return self.exclude(group_set__pk=group.pk)

    # etc..

class Member(models.Model):
    # fields..

    objects = MemberQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Then you can do this..

```py
Member.objects.in_group(group1).not_in_group(group2)
```